# How to remove 1st,2nd and last index of array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am using `array_splice` to remove 0th and 1st index of an array and I want to remove last index too.

How to do it?

```
array_splice($arr, 0, 2);
```

Here is my array -

```
Array ( [code] => 1 [name] => Abc [On] => 15619 [OP] => 15886 [Vac] => 31505 [Target] => 50702 [Co] => 62.14 )
```

Comment: array_splice($arr, (count($arr)-1), 1);

Comment: Tip: `array_slice(array_values($arr), 2, count($arr)-3);`

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions  add this as a solution. it's perfect

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions - you can also use a negative offset (-1) for the 3rd argument, rather than count-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_splice` with proper syntax can extract the array you want.

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
$newArr = array_splice($arr, 2, -1);
print_r($newArr);
// prints
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 2):

please try this

```
     $a1 = Array ( 
           'code' => 1,
           'name' => Abc, 
           'On' => 15619, 
           'OP' => 15886, 
           'Vac' => 31505, 
           'Target' => 50702, 
           'Co' => 62.14 );
       echo "<pre>"; 
       print_r(array_splice($a1,2,-1));
```

Output will be

```
Array
(
    [On] => 15619
    [OP] => 15886
    [Vac] => 31505
    [Target] => 50702
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in this simple way:

`$arr = array_slice($arr, 2, count($arr)-3, true);`

- offset 2 for skipping the first 2 entries
- -3 because second arg is for length not second offset or range

Comment: `$arr = array_slice($arr, 2, -1, true);`

Comment: @Mark Baker OK, thnx

Answer (score 2):

Just use two [`shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) and one [`pop`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) operations on the main array.

```
$array = your_array();

array_shift($array); //remove 1st
array_shift($array); //remove 2nd
array_pop($array); //remove last

print_r($array); //required array
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the easiest solution I have got.

array_pop

(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
array_pop — Pop the element off the end of array

```
<?php
$stack = array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry");
$fruit = array_pop($stack);
print_r($stack);
?>
```

Source : [php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

Comment: This is answer is simply wrong.  How does it have two upvotes?!?

Answer (score 1):

You can use more shorter syntax of `unset()` as

```
unset($arr[1], $arr[2], count($arr) );
```

Comment: FATAL ERROR Can't use function return value in write context

Comment: Plz check your answer, keep assoc keys in mind and the use of `count` here and that the first entry of an index is `0` not `1` in php

Answer (score 0):

You have two options while using splice function

First is:

```
array_splice($arr, 0, 2);
array_splice($arr, -1);
print_r($arr);
```

Second option is use splice function in smart way

```
$arr1 = array_splice($arr, 2, -1);
print_r($arr1);
```

Hope it will help you.